# Excel - Get username from AD based on display name in Excel sheet

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

So I've got this Excel sheet of employees which have all the information about them. I'm trying to import this info into AD, but in order to do that I need to get the username for these users as well. And I would like vba code or vb.net code that basically takes the value of every row in column D and looks for it in AD and returns the username and adds it to column A. Would something like this be possible?

Comment: I know the Excel side but am unfamiliar with AD. It would depend on the API for AD -- can you provide your best guess as to how you would proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with ADO.NET. I can't try it in my current environment but I've used it successfully in the past:

Add a reference to the ADO type library (msadoXX.dll).

Create a connection to ActiveDirectory using your own credentials. Sometimes it works without specifying your credentials (single sign on):

```
Dim Con As New Connection
con.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
oConnect.Properties("User ID") = "userme"
oConnect.Properties("Password") = "xxxx"
oConnect.Properties("Encrypt Password") = True
oConnect.Open "MyExcelConnection", stUser, stPass
```

Next create a command:

```
Dim command As New Command
Set command.ActiveConnection = oConnect
command.CommandText =
    "<LDAP://dc.company.com/ou=accounting,dc=company,dc=com>;(objectClass=user);displayName,mail;subtree"
```

Then execute the query command:

```
Dim rs As ResultSet
Set rs = cmd.Execute
While Not rs.EOF
    X = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Y = rs.Fields(1).Value
    rs.MoveNext
Wend
```

Of course, you'll have to adapt the query to your needs.